# How to switch (or checkout) to a existing remote branch in Git without facing detached HEAD

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-fetch, git-detached-head, git-switch

At first when I clone the Git repository I am in the **master branch**. But I have already created a remote **develop branch**. I run `git fetch origin develop`. Then, I use  `git checkout develop` and it switched to a new branch develop like this:

[image]

It creates local new develop branch. How to switch to my **origin develop branch** remote one. If I use **git checkout origin/develop**.
It comes like this:

[image]

How can I switch to my remote develop branch?

Comment: don't use `origin`; it refers to the upstream branch

Comment: Similar post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-my-git-repo-enter-a-detached-head-state

Answer (score 6):

As in [matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67966054/1256452), you literally can't do what you are asking to do.  Git simply won't allow it.

Git's message here is, I think, confusing to beginners:

> Switched to a new branch 'develop'.
> Branch 'develop' set up to track remote branch 'develop' from 'origin'.

The phrase *remote branch* is misleading.  What does *remote branch* actually *mean?*  Different people will use this pair of words, exactly like this, to mean different things.  So Git should probably not use it at all.  A better message might be, e.g.:

```
Created new branch 'develop', with its upstream
set to 'origin/develop'.
```

Again, as in [matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67966054/1256452), this is almost certainly what you want to use.  But if you like, you can go ahead and use the detached-HEAD mode using either:

```
git checkout origin/develop
```

or:

```
git switch --detach origin/develop
```

This detached-HEAD mode makes sense if you merely want to *look at* that particular commit, and maybe even build a release from it, but not make any modifications.

If you want to do your own development, you need a (local) branch.  The tricky thing here is that *all* branches are, literally, local to your own Git repository.  Even the things I call *remote-tracking names*, such as `origin/develop`, are local to *your Git repository*.  Each Git repository has *its own names*.

You can view any other Git's names—those it will show you, that is<sup>1</sup>—and copy them to your own Git repository if you like, but your copies are *yours*, not theirs.  Their names are theirs, and your names are yours.

When you clone a Git repository, you get *all of its commits* and *none of its branch names*.  What you and the other Git repository *share* are the *commits*.  It's the *commits*, not the names, that matter.  The commits themselves have big ugly hash IDs, which are how Git actually looks them up in its big database of all-Git-objects.  Any *branch names* just let you—and Git—find certain hash IDs.  Other, non-*branch* names do the same thing, so non-branch names are just as good as branch names, with one particular exception: **checking out a non-branch name results in a detached HEAD.**

So, when you clone some Git repository from GitHub or Bitbucket or GitLab or whatever, your Git gets all their Git's *commits*.  Then, your Git takes each of their *branch names*, such as `develop`, and *renames* them.  Your Git sticks `origin/`<sup>2</sup> in front of each name.  Last—as the final step of `git clone`—your Git effectively runs `git checkout` or `git switch` to *create* one new local branch, typically `master` or `main`,<sup>3</sup> with its *upstream* set to the `origin/` version of that name, which your Git copied from the other Git's un-prefixed version of that name.

(Parts of Git refer to this as *tracking*, which is another badly overloaded word.  Your local branch is said to *track* its upstream.  The *upstream setting* of a branch is just one of the various names in your repository, such as the `origin/` version of the same name.  Parts of Git refer to things like `origin/develop` as a *remote-tracking branch name*.  I call these *remote-tracking names*, leaving out the badly overloaded word *branch*, but still with the somewhat overloaded *tracking* part.)

Later, you'll run `git fetch`—or have `git pull` run `git fetch` for you—and your Git call call up their Git to see if they have new commits in their repository.  If they do, your Git will bring over their new commits.  Your Git will see if their Git repository has changed the commit hash IDs stored in their branch names, and if so, will update your *remote-tracking names:* your `origin/develop` will update to remember where their `develop` is now.

In between `git fetch`-es that you run, their `develop` could be updated, and you won't know.  So when you're wondering *did they update their `develop`?* that's when you would run `git fetch`.  If they *did* update their `develop`, you will get any new commits from them, and your Git will update your `origin/develop` to track the update to their `develop`.  That's why your `origin/develop` is a *remote-tracking name*.

In any case, this is why *remote branch* is such a poor phrase: does it mean `develop` on the other Git?  Does it mean `origin/develop` in your own Git repository?

---

<sup>1</sup>There's a set of facilities in Git, none of which seem quite satisfactory to me, for keeping various hidden names on Git servers.  Since all of them have various flaws, few servers actually seem to make a lot of use of these—but I have no direct insight into how GitHub, Bitbucket, and GitLab run their services, so maybe they do use them and they work better than I think. :-)

<sup>2</sup>You can make Git use something other than `origin` here, but that's the default and hence what you are seeing.  Technically these remote-tracking names are in a separate [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace), too, but we won't go into that here.

<sup>3</sup>The old standard, automatic first branch name was `master`; GitHub changed theirs to `main` and many have followed.  There's nothing special about either name though, and your project might have a different first-branch-name.  When you run `git clone`, you get to tell your Git which of their Git's branch names you want to copy, using the `-b` option.  If you don't pick one, your Git asks their Git what they recommend, and copies that one.  That's how your Git will follow GitHub's `main` recommendation, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I switch to my remote develop branch?

You can't. You cannot work on a remote branch.

The way to start working at the end of a remote tracking branch is to branch locally from that point, usually using the same name and usually tracking the remote tracking branch.

Normally, if you have fetched `origin/develop`, this should work automatically to do just that:

```
git checkout develop
```

That is what your Git did in response, *and it was correct*. You should learn how branches work if you still don't see why.

As for your detached head: the *only* thing you can `checkout` without getting a detached head is a local branch name.

Answer (score 2):

You typically won't want to be working directly with the remote tracking branches.  Instead, you would do a `git fetch` and then create a new *local* branch from the latest remote tracking branch, something like this:

```
git fetch origin                             # update remote tracking branch
git checkout -b your_develop origin/develop  # create new local develop branch
```

Comment: then if  I use `git checkout develop` is it same as I am in remote develop branch. caz it creates a new develop branch

Comment: @Mandara Not exactly.  That would be the case if you were to go a `git pull origin develop` while on the local `develop` branch.  The option I gave leaves open the possibility that your local `develop` branch be in some other state, but you still want to create a new branch from `origin/develop`.

Comment: That mean we can 't switch the branch to our remote develop branch. Only thing we can do is create a new branch from  `origin/develop`

Comment: You _can_ switch to the remote tracking branch but you probably _shouldn't_ do that.  The remote tracking branches exist locally as proxies for the true remote branches which live in the repository.

Comment: then what is the command for switching to my remote tracking develop branch. I want to switch to my remote develop branch. Not to create a new develop branch tracking with origin/develop

Comment: Use `git checkout origin/develop`.  But my answer basically is already doing this.

Comment: If I use this `git checkout origin/develop`  then detached Head state is coming.That's the problem

Comment: You shouldn't be doing work on that branch.  If you want to create a new branch _from that point_, then do `git checkout -b my_develop` from your current state.  Or just use my answer and avoid all this.

Answer (score 1):

When you check out `develop`, git doesn't complain the branch doesn't exist, so either

- you have a local branch named `develop` that you should delete (`git branch -D develop`) CAUTION may lose local progress there
- it really is checking out the remote branch

when you check out `origin/develop`, you're inspecting your copy of the remote's branch, which is why it has a detached head